# UWP - Bind a Vector to a ComboBox in c++

Tags: xaml, vector, combobox, uwp, c++-cx

I've got a combobox im my UI. In my network class I've got a method which recieves udp-packets and takes the IPaddresses from them. Which datatype do I take for saving the addresses as strings (Vector, IVector ?). And how do I connect this object ,which has the addresses, to my combobox in the UI - so each address is shown dynamically in the combobox .
I am using c++ for the network class and xaml + c++ for the UI. To avoid confusion, I am using the UWP-XAML-C++ template from Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which datatype do I take for saving the addresses as strings (Vector, IVector ?)

Yes, [Vector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/platform-collections-vector-class) can be used as the collection binding to the [`ComboBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox). More details about C++/CX  collection please reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/collections-c-cx).

> And how do I connect this object ,which has the addresses

For this we need to use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/index).

For example, suppose there is a `network` class contains `IpAddress` property as follows:

Code in MainPage.xaml.h

```
public ref class MainPage sealed
{
public:
    MainPage();
private:
    void btnbinding_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e);
};

public ref class network sealed
{
public:
    property Platform::String^ IpAddress;
};
```

Then we can bind the `network` collection(vector) to the `ComboBox` as follows:

XAML Code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combo" >
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IpAddress}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Code behind

```
void CombboxC::MainPage::btnbinding_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Platform::Collections::Vector<network^>^ items = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<network^>();  
    network^ onenet = ref new network();
    onenet->IpAddress = "Test";
    items->Append(onenet);
    combo->ItemsSource = items; 
}
```

Comment: this is not quite what I meant, I've got a loop in the network class for filling up the vector with the addresses. I don't want it to be filled in the code behind. My biggest problem is how to make a global vector in c++ which is read by the main-UI-class. I know how to do it in java/c#, but I failed creating a global vector in c++.